# How about including a small amount of example code in a large framework?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, example-code

I am about to upload a fairly large project of mine, a very flexible component-entity-system. More precisely it's a framework for a CES. It consists of 22 files, ~1000 lines of code and 20000 characters.

My problem is that in order to demonstrate what the framework does, I have 2 base component types (input, graphics) and 2 types of entities included in the framework. This is basically example code, unlike the framework itself. The base components have empty implementation too. However if I omitted these "examples" the usage and usefulness of the framework would be rather inconvenient to figure out. So I have empty implementation of base components and components specific to the particular entities (deriving from base components), because **these classes' pure existence gives meaning to the framework's capabilities**. Although having this kind of empty implementation is pretty much like having pseudo-code (even if everything compiles) and these tiny segments of code are not open to being reviewed therefore.

As an example here is an *example* component of an entity, where `InputComp<>` is the abstract base class for all `InputComp< 'entity name' >` classes.

```
template<>
class Comp<CompBase::INPUT, void> : public CompBase
{
    // Abstract Input component implementation.
};
template<typename Ent_t = void>
using InputComp = Comp<CompBase::INPUT, Ent_t>;

// in another part of the code
template<>
class InputComp<Monkey> : public InputComp<>
{
    // Monkey specific Input component implementation.
};
```

So is it okay to have a **small amount** of *example-like* code breathing life into a framework, included in the framework, given proper labeling of these segments.

Comment: We don't often say something is too big to review, but uploading your entire framework as a whole will not work in your favour. Why don't you select specific parts of your framework instead?

Comment: It only makes sense to interpret it holistically, I think. It is written rather cleanly and it is indeed really flexible so I'm sure you will like it :P

Comment: Prefer readability over brevity. InputComp -> InputComponent, CompBase -> ComponentBase, Comp -> Component (possible name collision..) You see, you can even get feed-back here :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, example code as a small part of a question, clearly labeled as example not for review, is perfectly fine, and even helpful.

That is assuming the rest of the question is real, fully working code, as per our [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) rules in the help center.

And as [@Mast](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast) pointed out, keep in mind that it's difficult to get good answers when you post a lot of code. You might want to split to multiple questions, highlighting different parts. That's not a *rule*, just a tip, for your consideration, to make the most out of your post.

Comment: The code should be real, the implementation may be an example. It's similar to including usage instructions.